# Работа с картами признаков сверточных сетей

Tags: нейронные-сети

При просмотре большого кол-ва статей по свёрточным сетям в интернете все объяснения работы СНС сводились к объяснению схемы на подобие приведенной ниже. Однако никто не объясняет четко, как взаимодействуют карты признаков в одном слое между собой (из них создается одна карта в виде взвешенной суммы или они все идут обособленно дальше по алгоритму и к каждой карте применяется новый слой отдельно) и как получается, что кол-во карт признаков увеличивается вдвое с каждым новым слоём. Я был бы признателен, если бы кто-нибудь объяснил схему взаимодействия карт признаков на одном уровне или скинул ссылку на статью, четко описывающую данную часть работы сверточной нейронной сети.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, фишка заключается в том, что если мы имели 2D фильтры(или ядра свертки) на входе (например, 10 штук), то на следующем слое мы используем уже фильтры 3D, размерность которых соответствует k * k * n, где k - размер фильтра на текущем слое, n - количество карт признаков, полученных с предыдущего слоя. Таким образом, мы получим трехмерные фильтры, которые обработают все корректно и четко. Отвечу и на вторую часть вопроса: секрет увеличения количества карт признаков заключается именно в том, что мы просто берем кол-во фильтров на новом слое в два раза больше, и за счет взятия их с соответствующей размерностью (как было описано ранее) никаких конфликтов с кол-вом карт признаков на следующем слое не возникает.